# Div container is not stretching the main full width div

Tags: html, css

I want to make layout where I will have different full width backgrounds. For example top is full width orange color, inside the full width div I have container that keeps everything in specific dimension (width: 1000px). And I met a problem, The content of the container div doesnt stretch the full width div. So right now to keep it work, I have to set in .orange and .red specific height. But this is not the solution, because right now my block has xxx heights, what If I add something like more pictures - I have to set bigger hight etc...

Here is what I mean:

HTML

```
<div class="full-width orange">
    <div class="container">
        content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="full-width red">
    <div class="container">
        content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.full-width {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I am sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which browser are you using?  I created http://jsfiddle.net/wVCLT/ with your original code and http://jsfiddle.net/wVCLT/1 without the 1000px specified.  As far as I can tell, things look right.  Based on the jsfiddle, can you provide more details of what is wrong?  Also, I'm testing in firefox.

Comment: On opera, firefox, chrome. Inside these container i  have elements on position absolute and I have elements that has floating left and right. But I keep clear them.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your code example to better show your problem?  I'm still fuzzy as to what is wrong.  You can update the jsfiddle i created (make changes and click "Update") and then other can see the code not working.

Comment: I've put a lot of code there. I might send it all more privatly, if there is someone who could help. If so, please provide me with an email to send it .

Answer (score 0):

if you put more content into your DIVs, they will stretch. their default height is auto (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) which automatically stretches the div to the height it needs to be. if you set height to a percentage, the div will be that percentage of it's parent container.

here is a JS fiddle for you to play with http://jsfiddle.net/dv9ah/
i set the

```
    height: auto;
```

in both the .red and .orange classes, but you can change them to a set height (like 100px) to see how they change.

Comment: Ok sorry my fault. You're right - if I didnt mess up, it would work fine. I just didn't noticed that I was duplicating class with position-absolute. That's why it didn't stretch the rest. 

Thank You for Your help.